# Is it possible to return an empty result even if it's empty in Neo4J Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Cypher Neo4j query:

```
MATCH (u:User{uid:'0ed0c7f0-8c55-11e4-8280-fbb0b27a7a0b'}), 
(ctxa:Context{name:'private'}), ctxa-[:BY]->u 
WITH DISTINCT ctxa,u MATCH (s:Statement), (ctx:Context), 
ctx-[:BY]->u, s-[:IN]->ctx, s-[:BY]->u 
WHERE (ctx.name="about" ) AND ctx.public = '1' 
RETURN DISTINCT s ORDER BY s.timestamp DESC;
```

It works fine, however, when there is no node `ctxa` matched in the database, the query doesn't go on, because it needs to have at least something.

So is it possible to override this setting and simply say that ctxa doesn't exist or make it an empty field for it to go on?

Answer (score 1):

You can use OPTIONAL MATCH for that case :

```
MATCH (u:User{uid:'0ed0c7f0-8c55-11e4-8280-fbb0b27a7a0b'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (ctxa:Context{name:'private'})-[:BY]->u 
WITH DISTINCT ctxa,u 
MATCH (s:Statement), (ctx:Context), 
ctx-[:BY]->u, s-[:IN]->ctx, s-[:BY]->u 
WHERE (ctx.name="about" ) AND ctx.public = '1' 
RETURN DISTINCT s ORDER BY s.timestamp DESC;
```

Comment: It didn't work, but maybe it's because I'm using 2.0.1?

Comment: mmh no, OPTIONAL MATCH is available since 2.0-RC1. Can you post the execution plan a.k.a PROFILE ?